# LXC utsname does not work

Tags: 12.04, lxc

I have created a LXC by cloning it from already existing LXC by using command `lxc-clone -o u1 -n u2`. When I start the u2 it comes with a prompt `u2 login`. Till this point it is fine. However, when I try to change the hostname by editing the `lxc.utsname = myLXC` and start the lxc again, I get the same prompt `u2 login` instead of `myLXC login`. Can any one suggest me how to change the hostname after creation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `lxc_root/etc/hostname` AND `lxc_root/etc/hosts` replace u2 with myLXC or

```
sudo -i -e 's/u2/myLXC/g' lxc_root/etc/{hosts,hostname}
```

Be sure to edit the files in your lxc root and not the host